# How do you change the backend.run() command?

Tags: qiskit

This is code from Chapter 6.1 of the qiskit textbook, which shows a job being run. How would you change the first line of the backend.run() command, the schedules parameter, in order to use it for a measurement for a constant pulse shape. The schedules parameter from the given code represents a frequency sweep that was defined earlier in the qiskit textbook. I want to keep the other parameters of backend.run the same and change the schedules part to something else and use this command on a constant pulse shape. I don't know exactly how to modify the schedules part of the command properly.

```
num_shots_per_frequency = 1024
job = backend.run(schedules, meas_level=1, meas_return='avg', shots=num_shots_per_frequency)
```

Comment: By first line do you refer to the first argument, i.e., `schedules`?

Comment: Hello, could you explain what you want to do exactly? We'll be more helpful if you add more details :)

Answer (score 2):

**Example 1**

> The backend defaults provide a starting point for how to use the
> backend. It contains estimates for qubit frequencies and default
> programs to enact basic quantum operators. We can access them with the
> following:
>
> ```
> backend_defaults = backend.defaults()
> ```

As you can see `backend`  itself is a command. You can change it with loading parameters (here `defaults()` parameters).

---

**Example 2**

Or another example, `backend_config` equals `backend.configuration()`. The `configuration()` is a method within the `backend`. The given name is `backend_config`. In the second line you see that the `object` `assert` will be defined by the `backend_config.open_pulse`. That's how you change the backends parameter. Just normal programming. I suggest to get more familiar with `python`.

```
backend_config = backend.configuration()
assert backend_config.open_pulse, "Backend doesn't support Pulse"
```

In conclusion you modify the `backend` with a `method` (`configuration()`) and change the methods `parameter` applied on the `backend`.

PS: `run()` is just a `method` also.